# text-align: center won't work unless inline css

Tags: html, css

I thought I would never have to ask something like this. But here is goes.

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>

<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .center_mobile { text-align: center; background: #ccc; width: 300px; }
</style>

<div class="center_mobile">Dumb!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Why the text on the div is not centered on its container as instructed by text-align?

However this centers the text:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">Dumb!</div>
```

I don't want to enter the style inline. How to fix this "problem"?

Code can be run here: http://www.practiceboard.com/?936248

Thanks.

**UPDATE AND "FIX"**

Removing the white space on that style solved the problem.

```
.center_mobile {text-align:center; background: #ccc; width: 300px; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the whitespace before the `text-align` rule in your css block.

Comment: I still can't explain the logic behind this other than a bug (?). Removing the white space fixed it. .center_mobile {text-align:center;...} Strange.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` tag needs to be in the `head`

If you inspect the element, you'll see you have a white space before the text-align rule. Remove it, place the style in the head and you're good to go. Demo: http://www.practiceboard.com/?936288

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .center_mobile {text-align: center; background: #ccc; width: 300px; }
       </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="center_mobile">Dumb!</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you include an example of the code with the style tag in the head.

Comment: I am not sure it is compulsory.

Comment: even though it isn't necessarily best practice, `style` tags work in the body

Comment: Thanks, however that is not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>

<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .center_mobile { margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; text-align: center; background: #ccc; width: 300px; }
</style>

<div class="center_mobile">Dumb!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

http://www.practiceboard.com/?936279

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

added to the class will center the text for you.

Comment: You need to say what you have done, otherwise this isn't helpful.

Comment: Sorry, i've added the margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; to the class

Comment: That centers the whole block on the parent element, but text stays on the left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;`, full css:

```
.center_mobile { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center; 
    background: #ccc; 
    width: 300px; 
}
```

Comment: <div> elements are display: block as default